How to respond a 'tag question'
Mike hardly puts up his hand in class, does he? ____He is one of the most active students in our class.
Which one should I put into the blank?'yes'or'no'?
I asked the chatgpt ,it told me when responding to tag questions, you're agreeing or disagreeing with the speaker's assumptions. So, I'm supposed to say 'No' here.
But the answer to this question is 'yes' .It says only to answer the facts, if the facts is 'yes',then'yes'. Given that 'He is one of the most active students in our class',which implies the fact is yes.
I'm so confused now
Help me please

Your textbook is wrong. Answering 'yes' would make the reply nonsense - if Mike is 'active', he presumably does put his hand up a lot!

hardly is a negative polarity item, same as never, rarely, doesn't,... Tags questions reverse the polarity of the preceding assertion, so it's ...,does he? Switch to a positive polarity element and we have  Mike sometimes / often / usually /  puts up his hand in class, doesn't he?

Does this answer your question? Which question tag is correct: “do / don't / have / haven't they?”

Welcome to ELL. I often wish that every computer were programmed to catch users’ attempts to ask ChatGPT for guidance on English and flashed up a big red warning: “CAUTION: ChatGPT’s advice on language is worse than useless; it’s often flat wrong. Never seek or trust its advice.”

If this is an exercise where you know that the only options allowed are yes and no, then I would choose No.

Mike hardly puts up his hand in class, does he?
No, he is one of the most active students in our class.

I've chosen no because I'm reading this as question and answer. The questioner is asking if Mike participates in class. He assumes Mike doesn't participate, and we know this by the leading question format. "He doesn't do X, does he? But the reply contradicts that assumption. "No, you're wrong. He does participate."
So the purpose of beginning the second sentence with no is to emphasise that the reply contradicts the implied statement in the original question.
